# Nginx redirect is causing issues

Tags: nginx, redirect

I've got a problem that I hope is simple.

I have a wordpress plug in that produces a link to a picture when a user chooses to share it. I have discovered that the link is properly formed and should work

It looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/nextgen-share/6064/872/thumb?uri=/the-galleries/headshot-gallery/
```

When that link hits the server coming back in it changes to

```
http://www.example.com/?q=/nextgen-share/6064/872/thumb?#gallery/6064/872
```

Wordpress chokes on that link and directs the visitor to a gallery page with no images .

I have narrowed it down to a line in my nginx conf.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

This is needed to make the permalinks work I guess.

My question is how to make the generated url work correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have:

```
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
   }
```

in your nginx config to enable custom link format...  and that works just fine for permalinks, but it can break other stuff.

So, replace it with:

```
   location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
   }
```

Wordpress's index.php will handle that just fine, so you'll still get your nice looking permalinks, but it won't break stuff the way what you had would.